# Content approval before publishing in joomla 3

Tags: joomla-3.x, php

I am currently using joomla 3. I have a scenario where by content has to go through approval before it is published

Comment: Welcome at Joomla Stack Exchange! Could you please elaborate on your question? Please describe how your approval process would look like. If you are looking for support regarding a coding attempt that you have made, please include that in your post. If you are looking for an extension, have you looked in the Joomla Extension Directory?

Comment: Perhaps this is what you are Looping for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53105002/4260616

Comment: @mike your question has been flagged for plagarism since it is a copy-paste duplicate of the first sentence in the question linked by astridx.  Are you also "maurice"?  If so, that's okay, I would like you to merge your Stack Exchange accounts.  It is ALWAYS important to cite anything that is not yours when posting in Stack Exchange.  It is okay to re-ask something if another page doesn't quite resolve your problem.  If you are not maurice, I would expect that your _actual_ coding attempt will be unique -- that should be [edit]ed into your question.